# Adding a HttpMessageHandler to the client returned by TestServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In this simple integration test, I would like to use a custom DelegatingHandler for the HttpClient.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MiddlewareIntegrationTests
{
    private TestServer _server;
    private System.Net.Http.HttpClient _client;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                                 .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
                                 {
                                     services.AddRouting();
                                 })
                                 .Configure(app =>
                                 {
                                     app.UseRouting();

                                     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                                     {
                                         endpoints.MapGet("/api/helloworld", async context =>
                                         {
                                             await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
                                         });
                                     });
                                 }));
        
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task MiddlewareAddsCustomHeader()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/api/helloworld");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

In a normal client app, I would create the HttpClient like this:

```
    services.AddScoped<HttpAuthenticationHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient( "myCustomHttpClient" )
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpAuthenticationHandler>()
```

I havn't found any way of adding a HTTP Message Handler to the client that is returned by the TestServer.

Ideely, there would exist something like

```
_client = _server.CreateClient(new HttpAuthenticationHandler());
```

Can this be done?

Comment: It also has a method named `CreateHandler()`. You can use this handler to create your own handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method server.CreateClient() creates a client that is configured with the base address of your TestServer.

You can manually set the base address of your test server:

```
_server.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
```

From there your can create a client manually pointing at this base address and add the handler, e.g.:

```
public class MyCustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   // handler implementation
}
```

then:

```
var handler = new MyCustomHandler
{
    InnerHandler = _server.CreateHandler();
}

_client = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
}
```

Comment: Thank you the the answer. I wasn't able to make it work though, I get an System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. Either the request URI must be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
Also, this approach will use an actual network call right?

Comment: Looks like the problem was a missing forward slash at the end of the BaseAddress. Thanks alot!